# statsmodels: Fitting an aggregate SARIMAX over many time series

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting, arima, forecast

I have a set of time series for the same metrics at different locations, and I'm trying to fit a SARIMAX model over their sum (in aggregate) to have one model which can then predict on a site-by-site basis (as the values will be proportionally lower).

However, this isn't working and the model predicts very high values at the site level (as though it'd fit an intercept from the aggregate case).

Is there something I am missing in my code?

```py
    model = SARIMAX(data1, exog=data2, order=(1, 1, 2), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 52))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
    print(f"Global: {model_fit.summary()}")


    for site in sites:
        # make prediction
        newdfinner = df_site.loc[df_site.site == site, :].fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
        exog2 = newdfinner.loc[
            newdfinner["start_week_dt"] >= last_sunday, ["exog1", "exog2"]
        ].astype("float64")
        yhat = model_fit.predict(
            newdfinner[newdfinner["start_week_dt"] == last_sunday].index[0],
            newdfinner.iloc[len(newdfinner) - 1, :].name,
            exog=exog2,
        )
```

Also, I receive several warnings depending on the training range used (and the fit method), such as:

```
Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
[2] Covariance matrix is singular or near-singular, with condition number 1.19e+24. Standard errors may be unstable.
```

Are these likely to significantly affect the fit, and how could they be mitigated?

Also how can I measure how normally distributed the error terms are?

Do any of the summary metrics provide a measure of that?:

```
Ljung-Box (Q):                        5.96   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 0.87
Prob(Q):                              0.31   Prob(JB):                         0.65
Heteroskedasticity (H):               1.20   Skew:                             0.66
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.91   Kurtosis:                         1.67
```